# How to initiate the state after getting data from firestore automaticly

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i m a beginner in flutter and i m working on a history page in my app,
what i m trying to do is getting data from Firestore, then work on that data and stock it into a list so i can build my history items in the dashbord widget, the problem is that the items don't appear unless i refresh the state manually, and in my case i m using this filter icon, the fonction that gets me data is getVente() which im calling it in initState() , i want this fonction to execute in the moment that i load my page, so the items too, and not manually.
this is what's happening [image gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YFLd.gif)

and this is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'package:chips_choice/chips_choice.dart';
import 'package:stocknsell/Components/DownSelect.dart';
import 'package:stocknsell/Components/DownSelect2.dart';
import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRagePicker;
import 'package:stocknsell/Components/historyitem.dart';

final Color backgroundColor = Color(0xFF4A4A58);

class HistoriquePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = "/history";
  @override
  _HistoriquePageState createState() => _HistoriquePageState();
}

class _HistoriquePageState extends State<HistoriquePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isCollapsed = true;
  double screenWidth, screenHeight;
  final Duration duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _scaleAnimation;
  Animation<double> _menuScaleAnimation;
  Animation<Offset> _slideAnimation;
  Vente vente;
  List<Vente> list = List();
  List<Produit> produits = List();
  Produit produit = Produit();

  @override
  void initState() {
    getVente();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: duration);
    _scaleAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0.8).animate(_controller);
    _menuScaleAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0.5, end: 1).animate(_controller);
    _slideAnimation = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(-1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
        .animate(_controller);
    super.initState();
  }

  void getVente() async {
    bool trouve = false;
    await for (var snapshots
        in FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vente').snapshots()) {
      for (var ventes in snapshots.docs) {
        if ((ventes['client_id'] != null) && (ventes['date'] != null)) {
          if (list.isNotEmpty) {
            for (var sells in list) {
              if ((sells.clientid == ventes['client_id']) &&
                  (sells.date == ventes['date'])) {
                trouve = true;
                produit = Produit();
                produit.baseprice = ventes['baseprice'];
                produit.couttotale = ventes['couttotale'];
                produit.nbarticle = ventes['nb_product'];
                produit.prixpromo = ventes['prixpromo'];
                produit.nom = ventes['marque'];
                sells.produits.add(produit);
                sells.montant += produit.couttotale;
              }
            }
            if (!trouve) {
              vente = Vente(
                clientid: ventes['client_id'],
                clientnom: ventes['client_name'],
                date: ventes['date'],
                data: ventes,
                montant: ventes['couttotale'],
              );
              produit = Produit();
              produit.baseprice = ventes['baseprice'];
              produit.couttotale = ventes['couttotale'];
              produit.nbarticle = ventes['nb_product'];
              produit.prixpromo = ventes['prixpromo'];
              produit.nom = ventes['marque'];
              vente.produits = List<Produit>();
              vente.produits.add(produit);
              list.add(vente);
            }
            trouve = false;
          } else {
            vente = Vente(
              clientid: ventes['client_id'],
              clientnom: ventes['client_name'],
              date: ventes['date'],
              data: ventes,
              montant: ventes['couttotale'],
            );
            vente.produits = List<Produit>();
            produit = Produit();
            produit.baseprice = ventes['baseprice'];
            produit.couttotale = ventes['couttotale'];
            produit.nbarticle = ventes['nb_product'];
            produit.prixpromo = ventes['prixpromo'];
            produit.nom = ventes['marque'];
            vente.produits.add(produit);
            list.add(vente);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    screenHeight = size.height;
    screenWidth = size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          menu(context),
          dashboard(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  int tag = 0;
  List<String> options = [
    'Date',
    'Client',
    'Montant',
  ];
  final elements1 = [
    "Alger",
    "Harach",
    "Beo",
    "Said Hamdine",
    "Ain Naadja",
    "Kouba",
    "Garidi",
  ];

  _openPopup(context) {
    DateTime mindate, maxdate;
    Alert(
        context: context,
        title: "Filtres",
        style: AlertStyle(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Mom cake',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 34)),
        content: SizedBox(
          width: screenWidth,
          height: screenHeight * 0.6,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Trier par :",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Mom cake',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 34)),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ChipsChoice<int>.single(
                        value: tag,
                        onChanged: (val) => setState(() => tag = val),
                        choiceItems: C2Choice.listFrom<int, String>(
                          source: options,
                          value: (i, v) => i,
                          label: (i, v) => v,
                        ),
                        choiceStyle: C2ChoiceStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Text("Secteur :"),
                MyStatefulWidget(),
                Text("Client : "),
                MyStatefulWidget2(),
                Text("Montant de vente"),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 110.0,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'MIN',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8,
                      child: Divider(
                        thickness: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 110.0,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'MAX',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Text("Date de vente"),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 150.0,
                      height: 70,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.date_range_rounded,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          final List<DateTime> picked =
                              await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
                                  context: context,
                                  initialFirstDate: new DateTime.now(),
                                  initialLastDate: new DateTime.now()
                                      .add(new Duration(days: 7)),
                                  firstDate: new DateTime(2015),
                                  lastDate: new DateTime(2030));
                          if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
                            mindate = picked[1];
                            maxdate = picked[2];
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        buttons: [
          DialogButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text(
              "Filtrer",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
            ),
          ),
          DialogButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text(
              "Réinitialiser",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
            ),
          )
        ]).show();
  }

  Widget menu(context) {
    return ... some widget ...
  }

  Widget dashboard(context) {
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      duration: duration,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: isCollapsed ? 0 : 0.6 * screenWidth,
      right: isCollapsed ? 0 : -0.2 * screenWidth,
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: _scaleAnimation,
        child: Material(
          animationDuration: duration,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
          elevation: 8,
          color: backgroundColor,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 37),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (isCollapsed) {
                                _controller.forward();
                              } else
                                _controller.reverse();

                              isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        Text("Historique",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white)),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 15.0,
                              backgroundImage:
                                  AssetImage('assets/images/search.png'),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _openPopup(context);
                              setState(() {});
                            })
                      ],
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: list.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return HistoryItem(
                          client_id: list[index].clientid,
                          date: list[index].date,
                          clientnom: list[index].clientnom,
                          screenWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          documentSnapshot: list[index].data,
                          montant: list[index].montant,
                          produits: list[index].produits,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Vente {
  DocumentSnapshot data;
  String clientid;
  String clientnom;
  String date;
  double montant;
  List<Produit> produits;
  Vente(
      {@required this.clientid,
      this.date,
      this.data,
      this.clientnom,
      this.produits,
      this.montant});
}

class Produit {
  String nom;
  int baseprice;
  double prixpromo;
  double couttotale;
  int nbarticle;
  Produit(
      {this.baseprice,
      this.nbarticle,
      this.nom,
      this.couttotale,
      this.prixpromo});
}
```

Comment: Hello can you upload any error logs that you are getting with the implementation in the above code?

Comment: i m not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FutureBuilder** widget. Wrap your **ListView.builder** with **FutureBuilder**.

```
FutureBuilder<List<Vente>(
  future: getVente(),
  builder: (context, stream){
    if(stream.hasData){
       return ListView.builder();
    } else {
       return CircularProgressIndicator() ;
    }
  }

)
```

**Update your getVente() method**

```
Future<List<Vente>> getVente() async {
  bool trouve = false;
  await for (QuerySnapshot snapshots
      in FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vente').snapshots()) {
    for (var ventes in snapshots.docs) {
      if ((ventes['client_id'] != null) && (ventes['date'] != null)) {
        if (list.isNotEmpty) {
          for (var sells in list) {
            if ((sells.clientid == ventes['client_id']) &&
                (sells.date == ventes['date'])) {
              trouve = true;
              produit = Produit();
              produit.baseprice = ventes['baseprice'];
              produit.couttotale = ventes['couttotale'];
              produit.nbarticle = ventes['nb_product'];
              produit.prixpromo = ventes['prixpromo'];
              produit.nom = ventes['marque'];
              sells.produits.add(produit);
              sells.montant += produit.couttotale;
            }
          }
          if (!trouve) {
            vente = Vente(
              clientid: ventes['client_id'],
              clientnom: ventes['client_name'],
              date: ventes['date'],
              data: ventes,
              montant: ventes['couttotale'],
            );
            produit = Produit();
            produit.baseprice = ventes['baseprice'];
            produit.couttotale = ventes['couttotale'];
            produit.nbarticle = ventes['nb_product'];
            produit.prixpromo = ventes['prixpromo'];
            produit.nom = ventes['marque'];
            vente.produits = List<Produit>();
            vente.produits.add(produit);
            list.add(vente);
          }
          trouve = false;
        } else {
          vente = Vente(
            clientid: ventes['client_id'],
            clientnom: ventes['client_name'],
            date: ventes['date'],
            data: ventes,
            montant: ventes['couttotale'],
          );
          vente.produits = List<Produit>();
          produit = Produit();
          produit.baseprice = ventes['baseprice'];
          produit.couttotale = ventes['couttotale'];
          produit.nbarticle = ventes['nb_product'];
          produit.prixpromo = ventes['prixpromo'];
          produit.nom = ventes['marque'];
          vente.produits.add(produit);
          list.add(vente);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return list; // Add this here
}
```

**Explanation**

`FutureBuilder<T>` will wait for a future to be completed.

In this case, `FutureBuilder<void>` expected nothing, so as your method `getVente()` which returns void. It will wait until the code is completed, and notify the builder. In this case, you don't need to call `getVente()` method in initState, since FutureBuilder will do it for you.

You can also you `FutureBuilder<List<Vente>>` which is better, but you will need to change your code quite a bit. It expects a list of Vente objects, which you can use in your builder method.

`future.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting` will check if the future is still in connection, and not yet completed. In this case, the builder will show a `CircularProgressIndicator()`,

When the future is completed, it will then return the ListView.builder method.

You can find out more information about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) if you want.

You can also use **StreamBuilder** if you want the widget to be updated when the value changes.

```
StreamBuilder<List<Vente>(
  stream: getVente(),
  builder: (context, future){
    if(future.hasData){
       return ListView.builder();
    } else {
       return CircularProgressIndicator() ;
    }
  }

)
```

**Update your getVente() method**

```
Stream<List<Vente>> getVente() async* {
  bool trouve = false;
  await for (QuerySnapshot snapshots
      in FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vente').snapshots()) {
    for (var ventes in snapshots.docs) {
      if ((ventes['client_id'] != null) && (ventes['date'] != null)) {
        if (list.isNotEmpty) {
          for (var sells in list) {
            if ((sells.clientid == ventes['client_id']) &&
                (sells.date == ventes['date'])) {
              trouve = true;
              produit = Produit();
              produit.baseprice = ventes['baseprice'];
              produit.couttotale = ventes['couttotale'];
              produit.nbarticle = ventes['nb_product'];
              produit.prixpromo = ventes['prixpromo'];
              produit.nom = ventes['marque'];
              sells.produits.add(produit);
              sells.montant += produit.couttotale;
            }
          }
          if (!trouve) {
            vente = Vente(
              clientid: ventes['client_id'],
              clientnom: ventes['client_name'],
              date: ventes['date'],
              data: ventes,
              montant: ventes['couttotale'],
            );
            produit = Produit();
            produit.baseprice = ventes['baseprice'];
            produit.couttotale = ventes['couttotale'];
            produit.nbarticle = ventes['nb_product'];
            produit.prixpromo = ventes['prixpromo'];
            produit.nom = ventes['marque'];
            vente.produits = List<Produit>();
            vente.produits.add(produit);
            list.add(vente);
          }
          trouve = false;
        } else {
          vente = Vente(
            clientid: ventes['client_id'],
            clientnom: ventes['client_name'],
            date: ventes['date'],
            data: ventes,
            montant: ventes['couttotale'],
          );
          vente.produits = List<Produit>();
          produit = Produit();
          produit.baseprice = ventes['baseprice'];
          produit.couttotale = ventes['couttotale'];
          produit.nbarticle = ventes['nb_product'];
          produit.prixpromo = ventes['prixpromo'];
          produit.nom = ventes['marque'];
          vente.produits.add(produit);
          list.add(vente);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  yield list; // Add this here
}
```

Comment: it didn't work for me, the progress indicator still spinning without any result.

Comment: Try adding ` return;  ` at the end of  the line in getVente() method.

Comment: i tried, but it didn't work either, thanx for the help.

Comment: I see now where the problem, in your getVente(), you are actually calling a stream, rather than Future, so you need to use StreamBuilder. 

Future only called once, while stream connection stays as long as we don't close it. Hence, the error. I'll modify my answer a little bit.

Comment: I have updated my answer, try check. This time, the condition is checked based on the list, whether it has value or not.

Comment: same thing, the spinning keep running without any result, what can i do so you can maybe understand better the problem ?

Comment: I understand, but how you do it is different than how I normally do, so I am Improvising your method, buy guessing the result.  If you want to try other method, or want me to show how I usually do it, I can show it to you.

Comment: You can try watching this video to get some ideas  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYN46233cws